# Why does this format string stop working in .gitconfig

Tags: git

Consider following log command with format string:
`git log --date=short --pretty=format:"%ad %Cblue[%an]"`. It shows me the list of authors who made commits.

If put it in `.gitconfig` file in order to define an alias it stops working altogether:

```
[alias]
log-author = log --date=short --pretty=format:"%ad %Cblue[%an]"
```

`git log-author` displays absolutely nothing in my repo. Why is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid directly modifying `.gitconfig`. The rules for escaping illegal characters aren't always clear for the config files for git. Instead, use `git config --add alias.<alias name>` with single quotes around the command so the shell passes it all as a single argument to the `git config` command (if you are using a POSIX style shell). Something like:

```
git config --global --add alias.log-author 'log --date=short --pretty=format:"%ad %Cblue[%an]"'
```

If you are then curious, look in `~/.gitconfig` at that point, after `git` has taken care of the proper escaping for you. Mine shows the line as this when I look in the file:

```
log-author = log --date=short --pretty=format:\"%ad %Cblue[%an]\"
```

This seems to work as expected, printing the date and then the author name beside it in blue (which I assume was your intent).